# One-sided ideals in the algebra of endomorphisms of an infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

$\newcommand\End{\operatorname{End}}$Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional vector space over some field. It is well known that for each infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\kappa<\dim V$ the subset of $\End(V)$ of all those linear maps $V\to V$ whose rank is strictly smaller than $\kappa$ is a non-zero and proper bilateral ideal in $\End(V)$ and that, moreover, we in this way obtain all non-zero proper bilateral ideals in that algebra.

> What are the left ideals and the right ideals in that algebra?

For comparison, if $V$ is finite-dimensional, then the left ideals in $\End(V)$ are the  sets of the form $\{f\in\End(V):U\subseteq\ker f\}$ for some subspace $U$ of $V$, and the right ideals are the sets of the form $\{f\in\End(V):f(V)\subseteq W\}$ for some subspace $W$ of $V$. These two constructions work in the infinite-dimensional case too, of course, but surely do not exhaust the one-sided ideals — the bilateral ideals described above do not arise in this way, for example.

This is one thing that Jacobson left out in the second volume of his *Basic Algebra*, so the answer is probably not basic….

Comment: Let $Q$ be a set of subspaces of $V$, such that $\{0\}\in Q$, $W_1\subset W\in Q$ implies $W_1\in Q$, and $W_1,W_2\in Q$ implies $W_1+W_2\in Q$. Then $\{f:\exists W\in Q:f(V)\subset W\}$ is a right ideal. This encompasses both examples you mentioned: $Q=\{W:W\subset W_0\}$ in one case, and $\{W:\dim(W)<\kappa\}$ in the other case.

Comment: (1) The $\textbf{principal}$ left ideals in the infinite dimensional case are the same as you have described for the f.d. case. (2) The general left ideals are joins of principals. (3) This suggests a way to construct 'new' left ideals: let $\mathcal F$ be a filter in the subspace lattice of $V$. Let $L\subseteq \textrm{End}(V)$ be the collection of endomorphisms with kernel in $\mathcal F$. If $\mathcal F$ is not principal, then $L$ is a left ideal that is not of the form you describe.

Comment: You could consider a more general problem: given vector spaces $V$ and $W$, classify the left $End(W)$-submodules and the right $End(V)$-submodules of $Hom(V,W)$. In the special case when $W$ is $1$-dimensional the problem is to classify the vector subspaces of the dual space of $V$. This seems hard, and it seems to point to part of what is hard about the stated problem.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}$Call "linear filter" on $V$ a set $\L$ of subspaces of $V$ such that (a) $\{0\}\in\L$, (b) $W\in\L$, $W'\subset W$ implies $W'\in\L$, and (c) $W_1,W_2\in\L$ implies $W_1+W_2\in\L$.

Let $V,W$ be vector spaces (over a given field) and $\L$ a linear filter on $W$. Define $I_\L=\{f\in\mathrm{Hom}(V,W):f(V)\in\L\}$.

As suggested by Tom Goodwillie in a comment, it is natural to enlarge the setup to $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$.

**Proposition**:  Each such $I_\L$ is a $\mathrm{End}(V)$-submodule of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$. Conversely, supposing $\dim(V)=\infty$, each $\mathrm{End}(V)$-submodule of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ has this form.

In particular, each right ideal of $\mathrm{End}(V)$ has this form.

[The assumption on infinite dimension is probably unnecessary, but this is not needed for the latter consequence, since the finite-dimensional case is standard.]

Example: consider subspaces $W_n$ with $W_0\subset W_1\subset\dots$: the set of homomorphisms whose image is contained in some $W_n$ has the given form. But even if $W$ has infinite countable dimension, not every linear filter has this form (if $\L$ is maximal among those linear filters on $W$ consisting of subspaces of infinite codimension, then it does not have this form).

*Proof of the proposition.* Let $J$ be a $\mathrm{End}(W)$-submodule of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$. Define $\L=\{f(V):f\in J\}$. Clearly $\L$ satisfies (a) and (b).

To check (c), call "linear moiety" a subspace whose dimension equals its codimension. (I'm thus assuming $V$ has infinite dimension). I claim that (1) if $f\in J$ then there exists $f'\in J$ such that $\mathrm{Ker}(f')$ contains a moiety and $f'(V)=f(V)$, and (2) same but starting from a given moiety $M_0$, for every $f$ we can choose $f'$ such that $M_0\subset\mathrm{Ker}(f')$.

Actually passing from (1) to (2) is clear by precomposing by a linear automorphism mapping the given moiety to $M_0$. Fix a decomposition $V=M_1\oplus M_2\oplus M_3$. Let $p_i$ be the corresponding projections $V\to M_i$.

To prove (1), write $f_1=fp_1$ and $f_{23}=f(p_2+p_3)$. Both belong to $J$, and $f(V)=f_1(V)+f_{23}(V)$. Let $u$ be an automorphism mapping $M_1\oplus M_3$ into $M_1$. Then $g=f_{23}u$ also belongs to $M$ and vanishes on $M_1\oplus M_3$. Then $(f_1+g)(V)=f(V)$ (we use that $f_1$ vanishes on $M_2\oplus M_3$ while $g$ vanishes on $M_1\oplus M_3$). And $f_1+g$ vanishes on $M_3$.

Next we write $M'_2=M_2\oplus M_3$.

Now prove (c): given $W_1,W_2$, choose $f_1,f_2$ vanishing on $M'_2$, resp. $M_1$ with $f_i(V)=W_i$. Then $f_1+f_2$ has image $W_1+W_2$.

We have $J\subset I_\L$. Let us check this is an equality: let $W$ be an element of $\L$. So there exists $f$ vanishing on $M'_2$ such that $f(V)=W$. Let $g$ be an element of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ such that $g(V)=W$. If $g$ vanishes on a moiety, then there exists an automorphism $u$ such that $g=fu$ (just lift a basis of $W$ and complete) and hence $g\in J$. In general, write $g=g_1+g_2$ with each $g_i$ vanishing on a moiety and then $g_1,g_2\in J$ by the previous argument, so $g\in J$.

---

Here's not the analogue for left ideals.

Dually, call "linear cofilter" on $V$ a set $\L$ of subspaces of $V$ such that (a') $V\in\L$, (b') $W\in\L$, $W'\supset W$ implies $W'\in\L$, and (c') $W_1,W_2\in\L$ implies $W_1\cap W_2\in\L$.

Let $V,W$ be vector spaces (over a given field) and $\L$ a linear filter on $V$. Define $J_\L=\{f\in\mathrm{Hom}(V,W):\operatorname{Ker}f\in\L\}$.

**Proposition**:  Each such $I_\L$ is a $\mathrm{End}(W)$-submodule of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$. Conversely, supposing $\dim(W)=\infty$, each $\mathrm{End}(W)$-submodule of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ has this form.

Indeed, let $I$ be a $\mathrm{End}(W)$-submodule of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$. Define $\L=\{\operatorname{Ker}f:f\in I\}$. Clearly $\L$ satisfies (a'),(b').

Similarly as the previous case, one has to show that for every moiety $M$ of $W$ and $K\in\L$, there exists $f\in I$ such that $\operatorname{Ker}f=K$ and $f(V)\subset M$. This is dual to the statement (2) above and the verification is similar. One deduces (c') immediately.

Finally write $W=M\oplus M'$ (sum of moieties); if $K\in\L$, choose $f\in I$ with $\operatorname{Ker}f=K$ and $f(V)\subset M$. Let $g\in\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ be such that $\operatorname{Ker}g=K$. If $g(V)$ is contained in a moiety, then $g=uf$ for some automorphism $u$ of $W$, so $g\in I$. Otherwise write $g=g_1+g_2$ with both $g_1,g_2$ vanishing on $K$ and each being valued in a moiety. Then each $g_i$ belongs to $I$ by the previous argument, so $g\in I$. Hence $I=I_\L$.

---

Note: to completely claim a classification, one should clarify when $I_{\L_1}=I_{\L_2}$ for linear filters on $W$ (this might depend on $V$), resp. when $J_{\L_1}=J_{\L_2}$ for linear cofilters on $V$ (this might depend on $W$).

For instance if $\bar{\mathcal{L}}=\{K:K\subset\bigcup\mathcal{L}\}$ then for $V$ finite-dimensional we have $I_\mathcal{L}=I_{\bar{\mathcal{L}}}$. Similarly, if $W$ has uncountable dimension and $V$ has countable dimension, $\mathcal{L}\mapsto I_\mathcal{L}$ is not injective.

However if $\dim(V)\ge\dim(W)$, then $I=I_{\bar{\mathcal{L}}}$ determines $\mathcal{L}$ as the set of images of elements of $I$. To get injectivity when $\dim(V)<\dim(W)$, one can thus restrict to those linear filters consisting of subspaces of dimension $\le\dim(V)$ if $\dim(V)$ is infinite, and of subspaces of finite dimension if $\dim(V)$ is finite.